How to make a ParametricPlot3D into solid shape
so, how define the moment of inertia and center of mass of this frustum? I find this quite dificult, instead i can make this frustum to be a solid 3d and find the volume of the frustum code.
so, the code is like this
height = 5; radiusBottom = 3; radiusTop = 1;ParametricPlot3D[{(radiusTop + (radiusBottom - radiusTop)*u)*Cos[\[Theta]], (radiusTop + (radiusBottom - radiusTop)*u)*Sin[\[Theta]], height*u}, {u, 0, 1}, {\[Theta], 0, 2*Pi}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Red}},  Lighting -> "Neutral" ]


Edit
Another way is similar with  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/302959/72111
Clear["Global`*"];
height = 5; radiusBottom = 3; radiusTop = 1;
f[u_, θ_] := {((radiusBottom + (radiusTop - radiusBottom)*u)*
     Cos[θ]), ((radiusBottom + (radiusTop - radiusBottom)*u)*
     Sin[θ]), height*u};
ptss = Table[
   f[u, θ], {u, Rest@Subdivide[0, 1, 401]}, {θ, 
    Rest@Subdivide[0, 2 π, 101]}];
{m, n, p} = Dimensions[ptss];
bm = BoundaryMeshRegion[
  Catenate[
   ptss], {Table[
    Polygon[{{#1[[1]], #2[[1]], #2[[2]]}, {#1[[2]], #1[[1]], \
#2[[2]]}}] & @@@ 
     Thread@{Partition[Range[1, n] + j*n, 2, 1, 1], 
       Partition[Range[1, n] + (j + 1)*n, 2, 1, 1]}, {j, 0, m - 2}], 
   Polygon[Range[1, n]], Polygon[Range[1, n] + (m - 1)*n]}]
bm // Volume



ParametricRegion

height = 5; radiusBottom = 3; radiusTop = 1;
reg = 
 ParametricRegion[{((radiusBottom + (radiusTop - radiusBottom)*u)*
       Cos[θ]), ((radiusBottom + (radiusTop - radiusBottom)*u)*
       Sin[θ]), height*u} (1 - s) + {0, 0, height*u}*s, {{u, 0,
     1}, {θ, 0, 2*Pi}, {s, 0, 1}}];
RegionCentroid[reg]
MomentOfInertia[reg]



Or OpenCascadeLink.

Clear["Global`*"];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"];
height = 5; radiusBottom = 3; radiusTop = 1;
shape1 = 
  OpenCascadeShape@
   OpenCascadeCircle[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 
    radiusBottom, {0, 2 π}];
shape2 = 
  OpenCascadeShape@
   OpenCascadeCircle[{{0, 0, height}, {0, 0, 1}}, 
    radiusTop, {0, 2 π}];
loft = OpenCascadeShapeLoft[{shape1, shape2}, "BuildSolid" -> True];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[loft, 
   "ShapeSurfaceMeshOptions" -> {"AngularDeflection" -> 0.05}];
reg = BoundaryMeshRegion[bmesh]



Start your calculation with a Region instead of a Graphics3D:
cone = RegionIntersection[Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 7.5}}, 3], Cube[10]];
Region[cone, Axes -> True, Boxed -> True]


Then you can use MomentOfInertia and RegionCentroid:
MomentOfInertia[cone]

{{205.290996503, -9.55724040481*10^-7, -4.03306267506*10^-16}, \
{-9.55724040481*10^-7, 205.290996767, 
  1.31219218054*10^-7}, {-4.03306267506*10^-16, 1.31219218054*10^-7, 
  190.066357049}}

RegionCentroid[cone]

{6.24164753045*10^-17, 1.9134230954*10^-17, 1.73076923077}


You could use ImplicitRegion,  e.g.
ir = ImplicitRegion[{x^2 + y^2 < (3 - 2 z/5)^2}, {{x, -9, 9}, {y, -9, 
     9}, {z, 0, 5}}];
rpo[n_] := RegionPlot3D[ir, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotStyle -> Opacity[n]]
rpo[1]
Show[rpo[0.5],
 Graphics3D[{Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 5}}, 1], Opacity[0.3], 
   Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 5}}, 3]}], Boxed -> False, 
 Background -> Black
 ]


